# MP4 video is blurry when scaled up in windows media player

Tags: video, windows-media-player

When I open an MP4 video file in Windows Media Player, it is sharp in windowed mode, but very blurry when the video is scaled up (e.g. when I enter fullscreen mode, or even when I make the window slightly bigger than the videos resolution). I only have this problem with Windows Media Player; other video players such as default "Movies & TV" do not have this problem. I have tried multiple codec packs but this does not help. How can I improve the sharpness of the video?

- Part of the video as seen in windowed mode:

  [image: part of the video as seen in windowed mode]
- The same part of the video as seen in fullscreen mode:

  [image: the same part of the video as seen in fullscreen mode]

Some information about my system: I am running Windows 10 Home Edition, I have an AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT GPU and dual screens both with a resolution of 2560x1440. The video is 1920x1080 at 30 fps and has a data rate of 600kbps and a total bitrate of 727kpbs. Windows Media Player gives the following properties for the video file:

[image: video file properties]

Using metadata2go.com, I see that the codec is h264, (the long codec name is "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10" with codec tag 0x31637661). The pixel format is yuv420p and the encoder is "Lavf56.40.101".

Comment: What is the video resolution? What is your screen resolution? What codec is the video?

Comment: @Mokubai I edited the question to provide answers to your questions.

Comment: it is possible that for some stupid reason Windows Media Player is using a very bad but fast scaling method. Given it's age it might not know how to trigger the GPU scaling methods or is using the worst method available. It may be bundled with Windows, but there are far better programs with better performance these days. I notice in the options there is a "video smoothing" option, does that change anything? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CmhE.png

Comment: I just tried Windows Media Player on an mp4 and the performance was horrible, it looks like it was running at half frame rate, but was supposedly using a hardware decoder. What I notice differently though is that VLC is using not only the hardware decoder (seen in Task Manager -> Performance) but also is using 3D, presumably making use of DWM and newer features of the [WDDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model) drivers. It may be that Windows Media Player is using some obsolete (GDI?) method to access and draw at the screen resulting in poor performance and scaling.

Comment: @Mokubai Good comment! Unfortunately the "video smoothing" option did not make a difference.

Comment: In WMP, if I go to Help > About > Technical support information I see this list of video codecs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9t3c.png I don't see mp4 anywhere however, but a couple of formats which are close (mp4s, mp43, etc). It seems I'm not able to pick the codecs myself. Also, WMP doesn't seem to use the LAV decoder which is used by media player classic (it shows a system tray icon when it's used).

Comment: Media Player Classic comes with an internal LAV video decoder. To check if it's being used for playback, open MPC's `Play` - `Filters` menu and check for `LAV Video Decoder (internal)`. If you install the [LAV filters](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/releases) separately, does WMP use its video decoder then? It might also be interesting to see what happens when you disable the internal LAV video decoder in MPC's options.

Answer (score 0):

- you are downsizing the capture;
- when you try to use full screen view, it MUST then scale up;
- scaling up is a quality loss, as is scaling down, compounding the issue; especially with lossy compression techniques;
- mpeg compression is especially brutal on hard-edge color transitions such as text on solid colors.

Comment: I understand how scaling works, but the point is that windows media player blurs the video when scaling up (the blurriness is significantly more than you would expect from just scaling up, which can be seen in the images I included in the questions). *Other video players do not have blurry video.*

Comment: You cannot control what other users use to view the video

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your remark. My question is "Windows media player playback is blurry when scaling up. How do I solve it?". I would think that I am the user here.

Answer (score -2):

Windows Media Player doesn't appropriately scale at High DPI, when you change to fullscreen mode. The Media Player hasn't seen updates to it's codebase since a longer time and [apps](https://www.pcworld.com/article/552380/a-brand-new-windows-media-player-is-rolling-out-now-to-insiders.html) are set to be the successor of the WMP. This would explain, why other Players work flawlessly when playing the same file.

See this example from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-sub-process-dpi-scaling): [image: Example of DPI aware and unaware Application]

Comment: My understanding is that high DPI mode (which I do *not* use) is only for UI. I would not expect this to affect the video playback.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of the Microsoft Docs. 
Well, video playback is still affected by DPI Awareness, since it's also displayed in the UI.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried a lot of variations for the high dpi settings in the compatibility tab, but this did not help.